# Image Upload to Azure Storage Account does not work?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage-account

I am following (previous and) this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/modules/connect-an-app-to-azure-storage/10-exercise-connect-with-your-azure-storage-configuration?pivots=javascript to upload an image to the Azure Storage account.

After following all the steps and copying the final file given for index.js, when I run the app by node index.js:

```
$ node index.js
```

I suppose the created blobs will be logged and the corresponding sizes will be shown. The corresponding output is only:

```
Container photos already exists
```

Therefore I suppose the file uploading is not successful. Where could the error be (or what I should check to see why the file uploading does not work?)
Any comments are welcome. Thanks!

Comment: Try putting console.log after each step and see how far your program goes.

Answer (score 0):

**I tried in my environment and got successful results:**

**Code:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

require('dotenv').config();
const { BlobServiceClient } = require("@azure/storage-blob");
const  storageAccountConnectionString = process.env.AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING;
const  blobServiceClient = BlobServiceClient.fromConnectionString(storageAccountConnectionString);
async  function  main() {
// Create a container (folder) if it does not exist
const  containerName = 'container2';//container name
const  containerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(containerName);
const  containerExists = await  containerClient.exists()
if ( !containerExists) {

const  createContainerResponse = await  containerClient.createIfNotExists();

console.log(`Create container ${containerName} successfully`, createContainerResponse.succeeded);

}

else {

console.log(`Container ${containerName} already exists`);

}
// Upload the file

const  filename = 'image1.png';//filename
const  blockBlobClient = containerClient.getBlockBlobClient(filename);

blockBlobClient.uploadFile(filename);
// Get a list of all the blobs in the container

let  blobs = containerClient.listBlobsFlat();

let  blob = await  blobs.next();

while (!blob.done) {

console.log(`${blob.value.name} --> Created: ${blob.value.properties.createdOn} Size: ${blob.value.properties.contentLength}`);

blob = await  blobs.next();

}

}

main();
```

**Console:**

[image]

**Portal:**

[image]

> Container photos already exists

The above command shows when you run again the same you will get that command because you have created container name with photos so thats the problem here.

***I have also runned again once more I got same command:***

[image]*